# Clojure interop: resolve ambiguous method

Tags: tfs, clojure, interop

Programming against the TFS SDK (for java) in Clojure, I'd like to call a method `pendEdit` which has several implementations (copied from the javadoc of class `com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.soapextensions.Workspace`):

```
int pendEdit(ItemSpec[] specs, LockLevel[] lockLevel, FileEncoding[] fileEncoding, GetOptions getOptions, PendChangesOptions pendOptions) 

int pendEdit(ItemSpec[] specs, LockLevel lockLevel, FileEncoding fileEncoding, GetOptions getOptions, PendChangesOptions pendOptions) 

int pendEdit(java.lang.String[] paths, RecursionType recursion, LockLevel[] lockLevel, FileEncoding[] fileEncoding, GetOptions getOptions, PendChangesOptions pendOptions) 

int pendEdit(java.lang.String[] paths, RecursionType recursion, LockLevel lockLevel, FileEncoding fileEncoding, GetOptions getOptions, PendChangesOptions pendOptions)
```

In my desparation I came up with the following code - which looks to me like maximally type-hinted:

```
(defn checkout-file [^Workspace workspace file]
  (let [spec ^ItemSpec (item-spec-file file)]
    (.pendEdit workspace
               ^"[Lcom.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.specs.ItemSpec;" (into-array [spec])
               ^LockLevel LockLevel/NONE
               ^FileEncoding FileEncoding/AUTOMATICALLY_DETECT
               ^GetOptions GetOptions/NONE
               ^PendChangesOptions PendChangesOptions/NONE)))
```

Even that does not seem to solve the ambiguity - resulting in the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException (ts_files.clj:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5440)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:5857)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:340)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:331)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:409)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:381)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__4519.invoke(core.clj:4915)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:4914)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:4729)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:4766)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:4800)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
        at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:4881)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at user$eval1.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5414)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5391)
        at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2382)
        at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:235)
        at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:254)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:279)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:354)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:369)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at gf.source.teamsystem.api.ts_files$checkout_file.invoke(ts_files.clj:31)
        at gf.source.teamsystem.api.ts_files$eval297.invoke(ts_files.clj:48)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
        ... 31 more
```

What's there to be done to call the second implementation of pendEdit?

Comment: I don't think that is an ambiguity error. The first problem I see is that your '^ItemSpec' type hint is after the var instead of before. Change it to '[^ItemSpec spec ...', and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: You are right - it's not an ambiguity error. The parameter workspace was nil. D'oh.
Regarding the type-hint: I could imagine hinting the expression is the same as hinting the var!?

Comment: @steglig Could you please answer your own question?